# ElasticSearch: Query based on array value

Tags: elasticsearch

Needed some help.
I need to query documents based on the inner values of an array.

```
{id:1 , version:[1],…} 
{id:1 , version:[2],….} 
{id:2 , version:[1,2],…}
```

I needed to do faceted search and also query based on version value.
Example if i query for version 1, i should get:

```
{id:1 , version:[1],…} 
{id:2 , version:[1,2],…}
```

Example if i query for version 2, i should get:

```
{id:1 , version:[2],….} 
{id:2 , version:[1,2],…}
```

please help,
Karan

Answer (score 0):

this is helpful if data type of version is mapped as string

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/<index_name>/<type_name>/_search?pretty=1' -d '
{
  "query":
  {
     "query_string":{"query":"1*","fields":["version"]}
  },
  "facets":{"version_facet":{"terms":{"field":"version"}}}
}'
```